# what is the value of n such that the probability of having 5 or more defected items in an approved batch is less than 90%？

Tags: probability

Before shipping a batch of 50 items in a manufacturing plant, the quality control section randomly selects n items to test. If any of the tested items fails, the batch will be rejected. Probability of each item failing the quality control test is 0.1 and independent of other items. Approximate the value of n such that the probability of having 5 or more defected items in an approved batch is less than 90%

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a homework page

Comment: Assume that you have a known number $n>5$ of these trials. The probability of success is $p=0.1$. What is the probability of having no successes? How about exactly $1$ success? How about $2$? Then sum up to $5$ ... What is the expression that you get?